# How to clear Chocolatey cache in the free version?

Tags: windows, cache, chocolatey

Installation-file-cleaning is currently only available in [the licensed edition of Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-package-reducer) ([$96 a year](https://chocolatey.org/pricing)) and [the developers seemingly have no plans to offer cache-cleaning support for the free version](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1124).

The package installation files can easily take gigabytes of storage space and to my knowledge they only increase in size as the user updates packages and installs new software, with only your hard drive capacity as the upper limit.

I don't know if Chocolatey stores cache in one central location — something is saved to `~\AppData\Local\Temp` but the majority is located in the `lib`* folders in `~\ProgramData\chocolatey`. Also the log files in the `logs` folder total to over 100 MB on my system. Is there any way to fully clear Chocolatey cache without manually deleting directories?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You may use for cleaning the cache the unofficial but approved package of
[choco-cleaner](https://chocolatey.org/packages/choco-cleaner).

The installed package creates a Windows Scheduled Task to run `Choco-Cleaner.ps1`
every Sunday at 11:00 PM.

To install, run the following:

```
choco install choco-cleaner
```

To upgrade (unofficial) Choco Cleaner (Script + Task), run the following:

```
choco upgrade choco-cleaner
```

You may also manually run this task immediately in one of the following ways
from the documentation:

- Command Prompt:

  ```
  \ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\choco-cleaner\tools\Choco-Cleaner-manual.bat
  ```
- PowerShell:

  ```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
  C:\tools\BCURRAN3\choco-cleaner.ps1
  ```
- Windows Start Menu: If you have `choco-shortcuts-winconfig` installed, you'll find it with the rest of the Chocolatey Shortcuts.

Comment: I had to change [PowerShell execution policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1) to run the script, may be worthwhile to add this information to the answer.

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Comment: Since the latest release, the PowerShell script seem to be here: `C:\tools\BCURRAN3\choco-cleaner.ps1` and the wrapper batch file is here: `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco-cleaner.bat` Not sure why this change has happened.

Comment: @GokulNC That is the location of choco shims,     

from https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-shim#usage: "Chocolatey ensures the folder "$($env:ChocolateyInstall)\bin" in the PATH environment variable, allowing you to put tools on the PATH without cluttering up the PATH."

Comment: I've been using chocolatey for a while... just ran this and freed up close to 5GB.
This is the way.

Comment: I found the script in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\choco-cleaner\tools\choco-cleaner.ps1

Comment: Right anwswer by @GokulNC! I was able to find the script under same directory `C:\tools\BCURRAN3`. Thanks!