# Why are there extra packages listed by Chocolatey and can I delete them?

Tags: package-management, packages, chocolatey

On opening the choco lib folder, I can see a lot of files. The only stuffs I remember installing were python and ffmpeg, and Chocolatey of course. But what are the rest? And there are 3 instances of Python? Can I delete them?

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib>choco list -lo
Chocolatey v1.1.0
chocolatey 1.1.0
chocolatey-compatibility.extension 1.0.0
chocolatey-core.extension 1.4.0
chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension 1.0.4
ffmpeg 6.0
KB2919355 1.0.20160915
KB2919442 1.0.20160915
KB2999226 1.0.20181019
KB3033929 1.0.5
KB3035131 1.0.3
python 3.11.4
python3 3.11.4
python311 3.11.4
vcredist140 14.32.31326
vcredist2015 14.0.24215.20170201
15 packages installed.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear Chocolatey cache in the free version?](https://superuser.com/questions/1371668/how-to-clear-chocolatey-cache-in-the-free-version)

Comment: Even after running the Choco Cleaner bat file all the previous files are still there :(

Comment: That's not a duplicate of this. Although I can see where the confusion may come from as the question was very poorly phrased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't let you delete most of them even if you tried, only the packages you installed are deletable. Because the extra packages include:

- dependencies - for instance, `python3` package requires `vcredist2015` as it can be seen [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python3/3.11.0#dependencies). `vcredist2015`, on the other hand, [requires](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/vcredist2015#dependencies) `vcredist140`. Then that [depends](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/vcredist140#dependencies) on multiple KB patches and Chocolatey Core Extensions. Etc. 

  The most common dependencies are Windows patches, Visual redistributables, .NET frameworks and other popular programming environments/runtimes like Java or Python. Read more about this concept in the [docs](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/package-dependencies).

---

- meta/virtual packages - learn about them in [this FAQ answer](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/faqs#what-is-the-difference-between-packages-no-suffix-as-compared-to.install.portable):

> Chocolatey has the concept of virtual packages (coming) and meta packages. Virtual packages are packages that represent other packages when used as a dependency. Metapackages are packages that only exist to provide a grouping of dependencies.
>
> A package with no suffix that is surrounded by packages with suffixes is to provide a virtual package. So in the case of `git`, `git.install`, and `git.commandline` (deprecated for `.portable`) – `git` is that virtual package (currently it is really just a metapackage until the virtual packages feature is complete). That means that other packages could depend on it and you could have either `git.install` or `git.portable` installed and you would meet the dependency of having `git` installed. That keeps Chocolatey from trying to install something that already meets the dependency requirement for a package.

In your case, `python` is basically a bit kind of different type of [metapackage](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python) that you install if you want to later update to the latest Python version, no matter if it's major or minor version change. It doesn't do anything itself, instead it depends on `python3`, which depends on a more minor version like `python312` and finally that package installs the software.

It's just a way to organize things.